# Automatically Updating Chart in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, date

I'm wondering why my code isn't working

```
Sheets("Chart").Activate

FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Date

For i = 2 To FinalRow
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Date Then
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("D2").Value
        Cells(i, 4).Value = Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("D3").Value
    End If
Next i
```

The loop appears to ignore the date value placed in column A. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should qualify all of your `Cells()` with a worksheet object, otherwise they default to the active sheet.

Comment: Also quality the `Rows.Count` with the sheet you expect the row count to occur on.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't need to qualify the references to cells and rows after activating the sheet you're working on. It won't make any difference to how your code operates. However, it is better practice because code is easier to read and safer because you don't have to always ensure the correct sheet is active when making changes to code. Not having to activate sheets also improves performance.

Answer (score 0):

You determine the FinalRow before adding the date to the cell below it. The For loop stops at the FinalRow, which is before reaching the cell with the date you added.

You either need to set the Date before determining the FinalRow, or loop i from 2 to FinalRow + 1